# Meaning of "isomorphism over the regular points"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

What does it mean that a proper, birational morphism (see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RN)) of locally Noetherian schemes $\phi \colon X \to Y$ is an isomorphism **over the regular points** of $Y$? I have two possible definitions in mind that seem quite natural, and I am not sure which one is correct and whether they are equivalent (the second is of course stronger, a priori):

- For each $y \in Y$ regular, there is a unique preimage $x$ and $\phi_x^\#$ is an isomorphism of local rings
- For each $y \in Y$ regular, there is an open (affine) neighborhood $y \in U \subseteq \mathrm{Reg}(Y)$ such that $\phi \colon \phi^{-1}(U) \to U$ is an isomorphism

**Edit:** I found this terminology in the definition of a *desingularization in the strong sense* in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves", Definition 8.3.39. Note that a birational morphism satisfies my first condition for the generic points of $X$ and $Y$, so I believe that this is what is meant, but I wonder if more is true.

Comment: Where did you encounter this phrase? It would be difficult to give a definitive answer to your question without knowing the context.

Comment: @Marc Paul Thanks for your comment, see my edit